# setResult called the same activity instead of calling the parent activity

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I am calling the intent from FirstActivity to SecondActivity.I called the startActivityForResult with the requestCode and Intent but in the SecondActivity setResult is calling the SecondActivity  instead of calling the FistActivity . This is my code

FirstActivity

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);                         
startActivityForResult(i,1);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"result"+data.getStringExtra("data"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

SecondActivity

```
Intent i=getIntent();
i.putExtra("data","hi");
setResult(1,i);
finish();
```

Manifest

```
<activity
 android:name=".FirstActivity"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden"
 android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"

 android:screenOrientation="portrait">
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="example"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".SecondActivity"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

Comment: remove this  android:noHistory="true"  from your manifest file

Answer (score 4):

Change from :

```
Intent i=getIntent();
```

to:

```
Intent i=new Intent();// change this line
```

Answer (score 1):

pass

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
```

instead of

```
setResult(1,i);
```

Comment: I have used fragments in that activity..Is that will be the problem?.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement it by having a new object of intent and lastly finishing current activity.

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("data","hi");
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: ya..I tried that..Its not working..I think SecondActivity is on top of the Satck .so its caling the same activity.if i give the nohistory for secondActivity onActivityResult will be called with data null..